# Dismiss DialogFragment onClick

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

I was trying to make a DialogFragment that could be dismissed when tapped, after some search i decided to go with this implementation:

```
public class ErrorDialogFragment extends RoboDialogFragment {

private static final String MESSAGE_ARG = "message";
private TextView text;

public ErrorDialogFragment newInstance (String message){
    ErrorDialogFragment f = new ErrorDialogFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(MESSAGE_ARG, message);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error_dialog_fragment, container, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ErrorDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
        }
    });

    text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.error_dialog_text_textView);
    text.setText(getArguments().getString(MESSAGE_ARG));
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
}
```

The alert dialog can have a custom message and will be dismissed when tapped.

Do you think is a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use **dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);** which will close the dialog if you touch outside the dialog. or

Try this tutorial http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html .
Hope it Helps..!!

Comment: Thanks @Raghav im using now the setCanceledOnTouchOutside, but for inside tap im going to continue with my approach, the link refers to an activity nor a DialogFragment :)

Comment: Can you tell me where do you call the setCanceledOnTouchOutside method? because i need dialog object for that

Comment: just write it where you are performing all other operations for dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon);
        alertDialog.show();
```

just use this code whenever you want to show the alert, and its ok onclick event the dialog box will dismiss.

Comment: Thanks @user1208720, but my class extends from DialogFragment (intentionally not an AlertDialog), and its not closed when a button is clicked rather when clicked on any place on the view.
The question is about using this DialogFragment class from the android framework and how to dispatch correctly events like this :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm calling a DialogFragment from an Activity. After click a button in the dialog I'm using an interface to call a method inside the activity. In that activity I'm executing this:

```
// This is the code inside the activity that call the dialog
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyDialog");
if(fragment != null) {
    DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fragment;
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```